# awk increment or change value of a column in a file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I have a bash script that runs a backup job and produce a csv file.

```
90927597|1356976813998|90927598
```

How can I increment / change the value of the 3rd column of my CSV file? ( I actually just want to make it uniq using a random value).

How can I get that done?

Thank you

Comment: `awk -F\| '{++$3;print}'`

Comment: Good idea, @jthill, I used part of it in my updated answer.

Comment: @jthill, you need to set `OFS=\|` somewhere in there

Comment: works fine, just wondering if I could increment the number not by one but lets say 10

Comment: @glennjackman True.  `awk -F\| '{$3+=10;print}' OFS=\|`, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the file `a`, `sed 's/hello/bye/g a' replaces all ocurrencies of`hello`with`bye`in the file`a`.

```
$ cat a
90927597|1356976813998|90927598
$ sed 's/90927598/hello/g' a
90927597|1356976813998|hello
$ 
$ sed -i 's/90927598/hello/g' a
$ cat a
90927597|1356976813998|hello
```

that is, `sed -i` replaces the file. Without `-i` it shows the replacement on stdout.

---

> each value in the third column with different value for each row, do
>   you think its possible?
>   just random, or use the same value + random value, the idea just to make it uniq

```
$ awk -v v=YOUR_SEED 'BEGIN {FS = "|"; OFS="|" } $3=++v' a > output_file
```

(idea got from [jthill comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489395/awk-increment-or-change-value-of-a-column-in-a-file#comment23665509_16489395))

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I can do this for a single line, my csv file has thousands of lines, do you how can I change the value of the 3rd column in the entire file?

Comment: Do you have to change each 3rd column with the exact same value or it is different for each row?

Comment: each value in the third column with different value for each row, do you think its possible?

Comment: But what value do you want it to store? Just a random one?

Comment: Yeah just random, or use the same value + random value, the idea just to make it uniq

Comment: what about the updated answer? You can give the program a seed (any number) and will create an output file with updated 3rd column with SEED, SEED+1, ...

Comment: @fedorqui `-v v=YOUR_SEED` could be removed. `++v` is uniq (1...n). even easier, `$3=NR`